# Access public property in usercontrol from codebehind without knowing usercontrol type

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

I wonder if it would be possible to access a property in a usercontrol without casting The specific typ of the usercontrol

Example:

```
var car = (Car)LoadControl("~/Vehicles/Car.ascx");
car.Brand = "Toyota";
```

Set the "Brand" property as above but without the "(Car)" cast.

Comment: Will `LoadControl()` always return a `Car` object?  If so you can write a new LoadControl function using the `new` keyword to change the type returned by the method.  Just call the base method and type cast the result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is possible, you will have to cast it to some sort of base type.

The other option is for you to make abase type or make them implement some interface and cast it to that type and then use it.

Closest you would get would be Dynamic key word new in .net4
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: Some kind of inheritance might be de solution. The problem is that I´m building a cms where you can add diffrent widgets (custom UserControls) into containers. 
I would like to populate all widgets with a widgetID and pageID without necessarily knowing the type of the userControl as I load the control with: LoadControl(string.Format("~/modules/{0}/Form.acx", widgetNameID));

It would have been simple if not the usercontrol already inherited System.Web.UI.UserControl.